# OrmLite join table by multiple columns

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

With OrmLite how can I join a table by multiple columns?

I have `Notes` table that can have data for either `QutoeHeader` or `OrderHeader` so I tried to join and use `SelectMulti()` like this:

```
var userSpecificQuery =
    _db
        .From<Customer>()
        .Where(x => x.SalesRepresentativeId == userId)
        .LeftJoin<Customer, QuoteHeader>((c, q) => c.Id == q.CustomerId)
        .LeftJoin<Customer, OrderHeader>((c, o) => c.Id == o.CustomerId)
        .LeftJoin<OrderHeader, QuoteHeader, Notes>((oh,qh, n) => oh.Id == n.OrderId || qh.Id == n.QuoteId)
    ;


var userSpecificRecords = 
    _db.SelectMulti<Customer, QuoteHeader, OrderHeader, Notes>(userSpecificQuery);
```

But I get error:

> table name "quote_header" specified more than once

I want to join all record that match either OrderId or QuoteId.  I tried a few different ways and get same error.  Is this possible?

edit:

Here is note model

```
public class Notes : BaseModel
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(typeof(QuoteHeader))]
    public long? QuoteId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(typeof(OrderHeader))]
    public long? OrderId { get; set; }
    public string NoteText { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of joining on `QuoteHeader` multiple times, move the condition into `Where`:

```
db.From<Customer>()
  .Where(x => x.SalesRepresentativeId == userId)
  .LeftJoin<Customer, QuoteHeader>((c, q) => c.Id == q.CustomerId)
  .LeftJoin<Customer, OrderHeader>((c, o) => c.Id == o.CustomerId)
  .LeftJoin<OrderHeader, Notes>((oh, n) => oh.Id == n.OrderId)
  .Where<OrderHeader,QuoteHeader,Notes>((oh,qh,n) => oh.OrderId != null || qh.Id == n.QuoteId)
```

Comment: Hey Mythz thanks for reply.  A Note can either have an OrderId or QuoteId (nullable long).  I think if I left join on OrderId then I won't get the records that have a QuoteId but no OrderId.

Comment: @Guerrilla you should be able to add it to the Where? I’ve updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  OrderId & QuoteId are fields on the note model (I updated original question).  The join won't get all the records so filtering by null won't work I don't think.

Comment: @Guerrilla you’ve already left joined on QuoteHeader? If that doesn’t do what you want you’ll need to [use Custom SQL](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/README.md#stored-procedures-using-custom-raw-sql-apis) as there’s no way for SelectMulti to unambiguously select from multiple of the same tables. If you didn’t need to use SelectMulti you could use [table aliases](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/README.md#table-aliases)

Comment: Yes I think this needs custom SQL.  When I went to make the raw sql I realised I needed subqueries and full outer join/union so probably easier to just split this out into multiple queries.  Thanks for help.